# Virtual base to derived cast of a non-polymorphic type

Tags: c++, inheritance, language-lawyer, dynamic-cast, static-cast

Base-to-derived conversion requires explicit cast though either `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`. When the base is virtual, only the latter applies. Furthermore, `dynamic_cast` can only be used on polymorphic types. Together, the two seem to suggest that it is practically impossible to convert a virtual base to derived given that the involved type is not polymorphic. Is this true?

Comment: Perhaps, but that's also an edge case: If the base doesn't have a virtual destructor, you won't generally have naked base subobject references lying around. In that case you will generally need to know the most-derived type anyway.

Comment: @KerrekSB I think without RTTI, such cast is impossible even in theory. To enable such cast, C++ has to generate RTTI also for non-polymorphic types. Such a burden :(

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation of the standard appears to be correct.

However I'm willing to argue that it doesn't matter, because your hypothetical virtual base with a non-virtual destructor is a disaster waiting to happen when someone attempts to polymorphically delete it and hits undefined behavior because the destructor is non-virtual.

Comment: Consider the case `void UseIt(const Base& base);` `delete &base` makes no sense.

Comment: @Lingxi: Nor does a downcast. All `UseIt` knows is that there's an object of a non-polymorphic type `Base`. Such an object, by design, does not provide any facilities to determine whether and where it is a dynamic (virtual) subobject, so `UseIt` cannot want to attempt such a determination.

Answer (score -1):

Dynamic/static casts apply only to pointers and references.

When the base is virtual, both static- and dynamic-cast apply.

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base() {};
};

class Derived : public Base {
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Base *b = nullptr;
  Derived *d = nullptr;
  d = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(b);
  d = static_cast<Derived *>(b);

  return 0;
}
```

Second part of the question : if the base is virtual, the derived type is polymorphic. What to you mean exactly?

Comment: By the word virtual, I take to mean virtual inheritance, not virtual methods.